# arquivo .Htaccess

Tags: html, htaccess

Estou usando a seguinte configuração no arquivo Htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?dominio.com.br$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pasta-destino/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pasta-destino/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?dominio.com.br$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ pasta-destino/index.php
```

eu preciso que a url do site fique da seguinte forma: `www.dominio.com.br/xs/index.php`, no entanto, esta fazendo o redirecionamento, mas a pagina `index.php`, esta totalmente fora da pasta fazendo com que ela fique totalmente quebrada, para que isso não acontecer tem que aparecer na url www.dominio.com.br/xs/index.php, é possivel fazer isso?

Comment: Não seria mais simples fazer um `header("location ./xs/index.php")` no www.dominio.com.br/index.php

Comment: Pode ser, não pensei nisso.
As vezes fico dando voltas, quando a solução pode estar bem na frente.